# How to upgrade my parsify() which can detect a function embeded in a string and replace the function with its output in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I have two functions namely **antiString()** & **parsify()** whose code is given below :

```
 function antiString(obj) { 
  return Function('"use strict"; return (' + obj + ')')();
 }; // This is a function I learned about from MDN Documents

 function parsify(str) {
   str = str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ");
   var mat = str.match(/@--func(.*)--@/).pop();
   var anti = antiString(mat);
   var str2 = str.replace(/@--func(.*)--@/, anti);
   return str2;
 };
```

Considering a very simple function, named as **calc()** :

```
 function calc(val) {
    return val.toString(); // Just changes the typeof val to string from our input type that will be number.
 };
```

Now usage :

```
 var str = "Value will be @--func calc(3/2) --@";
 console.log( parsify( str ) ); // Value will be 1.5
```

So, you may ask what is my question !! You may see that I used **pop()** in the source code of the **parsify()** ! That's my problem. As by defination, **pop()** refers the last, thus when ever I like to do something like this :

```
 var str = "I am @--func calc(4+1) --@, who is @--func calc(2-1) --@ added to @--func calc(16/4) --@";
 console.log( parsify( str ) );
 // Expected Output : I am 5, who is 1 added to 4
// Actual Output : Nothing !!!!!!!
```

So, I want to upgrade my So, I want to upgrade my parsify() function such that it can generate outputs as the expected output in the above example. Can anyone show me what to change to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a function for replacing the search part and use a non greedy `?` quantifier to get only the shortest possible search string.

BTW, you need no `;` at the end of the function block. This could be required by using [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).

```js
function antiString(obj) {
    return Function('"use strict"; return (' + obj + ')')();
}

function parsify(str) {
    return str
        .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ")
        .replace(/@--func(.*?)--@/g, (_, mat) => antiString(mat));
}

function calc(val) {
    return val.toString();
}

var str = "I am @--func calc(4+1) --@, who is @--func calc(2-1) --@ added to @--func calc(16/4) --@";

console.log(parsify(str));
```